# How might I simulate saturating HTTP.sys queueLength and causing 503s in IIS?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, iis-express

I'd like to trigger 503 "Service Unavailable" responses from IIS.

Following [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/tn-archive/cc745955(v=technet.10)), I've set queue length to 10 and triggered 10+ slow requests; however they must not be on the queue after they get to MVC and hit `Thread.Sleep`. What else can I do to simulate saturation?

Comment: You can use some test page like https://blog.lextudio.com/a-test-page-for-iis-cpu-throttling-8813f76c67d

Comment: Try turning MaxConcurrentRequestPerCPU to 1 and then fill up the CPUs:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/web/applicationpool-element-web-settings